# end up VS. come to VS. come down to

Tags: meaning

1. How did it end up like this?
2. How did it come to this?
3. How did it come down to this?

I couldn't find any differences between those. Can anyone be nice and help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you hate apples. One day you were famished and had nothing else but apples to eat, so you ate one. Someone noticing the eaten apple core might ask you,

> **How did it end up like this?** - Asking particularly about what happened to the apple.

> **How did it come to this?** - Inquiring what situation forced you to eat an apple you hate so much

And between 2 and 3, i don't see any differences.